# MySQL não conecta pelo getConnection() Netbeans Java

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Estou já a um tempo tentando fazer com que meu banco de dados MySQL conecte pelo `getConnection()`. Já tentei várias formas diferentes, de colocar o nome do banco, já vi varios tutoriais inclusive os tutoriais que são do próprio site do MySQL, vídeos, postagens na internet e nenhuma das soluções lá vistas resolveu meu problema!

Estou tentando usar o formato que não recorro ao driver manualmente uma vez que nas versões mais atuais do java isso é feito automaticamente.

Segue um print do do código que executei ao lado do banco conectado.

[image: descrição]

O erro é o seguinte:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql:@localhost:3306/Java
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at acessobanco.AcessoBanco.main(AcessoBanco.java:14)
/Users/Alecell/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.1/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
FALHA NA CONSTRUÇÃO (tempo total: 0 segundos)
```

Eu uso Netbeans no Mac com MAMP. Inicialmente a porta do MySQL era 8889, cheguei a pensar que seria esse o problema e modifiquei para 3306 mesmo assim não funcionou. Fiz uma verificação de se o banco de dados está funcionando na nova porta (3306) com o MySQLWorkbanch e está de fato funcionando, eu só não consigo efetuar a conexão via código java.

O JDBC foi instalado de várias formas diferentes e o **mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar** de fato está na biblioteca do projeto.

Comment: Oi Alexandre, você poderia por favor postar o código em formato texto ao invés de uma imagem? Abraços.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente adicionar isso ao seu código logo no começo do `main`:

```java
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    throw new AssertionError(e);
}
```

Se isso resolver o problema, então ótimo. Por outro lado, se ele estourar o `AssertionError` tendo como causa o `ClassNotFoundException`, então com certeza há algo de errado nas suas bibliotecas/classpath. Isso não deveria ser necessário, mas é inofensivo e servirá para denunciar algum problema de classpath, se houver.

Além disso, recomendo usar uma versão mais recente do connector, para evitar ter dor-de-cabeça com alguns bugs ou com a falta de alguma feature. Neste momento as últimas versões são a 5.1.39 e a 6.0.3 (milestone 2).

Por fim, evite colocar nas perguntas código apenas em imagens, prefira sempre texto pois fica mais fácil para quem for responder testar o seu código. As imagens servem apenas para quando o texto não for suficiente.

Comment: Olá, funcionou com o código que vc me passou, até me assustei quando rodou. Mas fiquei com a duvida do pq não estava funcionando sem este trecho de código, saberia me dizer?

Comment: No final das contas o problema era de fato a versão do JDBC do MySQL! Muito obrigado pela ajuda!