# Projeto JSP com Banco de Dados

Tags: java, jdbc

Estou trabalhando em um projeto JSP com banco de dados o meu driver não está sendo reconhecido.

Estou utilizando o seguinte método para conectar com o banco.

```
public ConnectionDB(){
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/loja";
        String user = "hxf";
        String password = "";
        con = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Estou utilizando o Tomcat. É retornado o seguinte erro.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1891)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1734)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at DAO.ConnectionDB.<init>(ConnectionDB.java:13)
```

Alguém tem ideia do que pode ser?

Comment: adicionou driver do mysql no seu projeto ?

Comment: Talvez isso seja uma duplicata dessa pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141603/132 - Embora a pergunta não seja exatamente a mesma, recomendo a mesma resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Faça o download do driver: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=465644

Adicione o lib na pasta LIB do Tomcat: [image: LIB tomcat]

Comment: Valeu galera. Consegui resolver. Eu adicionei o driver na pasta WEB-INFO/lib e funcionou.