# Como instalar uma aplicação java com banco de dados MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql

Eu estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação java desktop, com java swing e banco de dados MySQL. Porém preciso instalar essa aplicação em várias máquinas e gostaria de saber uma forma mais fácil para fazer isso, sem precisar instalar o MySQL em todas as máquinas.

É possível instalar uma aplicação usando o MySQL e não instalá-lo em cada máquina?

Fiz algumas pesquisas em vários fóruns e sugeriram os seguintes banco de dados: HSQLDB, SQLite, Derby, H2 e Firebird.

Há a possibilidade de hospedar o banco de dados em algum servidor na internet.

Gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma de resolução deste problema.

Comment: "*Todos os fóruns que li, mencionam não ser possível instalar uma aplicação usando o mysql e não instalá-lo em cada máquina.*" - Isso é uma mentira grosseira e sem nenhum fundamento. Que fóruns são esses afinal?

Comment: Pesquisei no guj, alguns daqui mesmo, dentre outros. Mas é possível fazer essa instalação ? Vou procurar o link e colocar aqui.

Comment: @VictorStafusa se for banco *standalone* não chega a ser mentira.

Comment: Se você quer embarcar o banco junto com a aplicação, onde cada maquina terá uma instancia propria, não é possivel utilizar mysql, pois ele é baseado em servidor. Agora se pretende fazer um banco apenas compartilhado entre varias maquinas executando sua aplicação, ele é uma opção, mas como disse, vai precisar de uma maquina para ser o servidor.

Comment: diegofm seria a primeira opção que vc falou mesmo, embarcar junto com a aplicação. Qual banco vc pode me sugerir ? Obrigada pela resposta.

Answer (score 4):

Vamos supor que você tenha publicado o seu servidor MySQL no host `bd.example.com`, na porta padrão do MySQL (3306) e que o usuário seja `fulano`, a senha seja `senha123` e a base de dados se chame `minhabase`.

Neste caso, você obtém um `java.sql.Connection` ao fazer isso:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://bd.example.com:3306/minhabase";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "fulano", "senha123");
```

Além disso, obviamente você deve ter o JAR do MySQL no classpath. [Veja mais sobre isso nesta minha outra resposta.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/141618/132)

Comment: O jar do mysql eu já gerei usando o maven, está parte já está funcionando. Mas entendi, eu mudaria a string de conexão e hospedaria o banco. Vc tem algum site para hospedagem de banco de dados para sugerir ? Obrigada.

Comment: @JéssicaDias Hospedagem de banco de dados, eu não sei. Faz anos que não vou atrás disso, pois normalmente eu mesmo hospedo o que preciso com recursos próprios. Entretanto, existem centenas de empresas por aí que vendem hospedagem MySQL.

Comment: @JéssicaDias, faz uma assinatura no Kinghost...lá é simples de usar e barato...